# How to write pseudocode and draw up a trace table for reading a text file

Tags: java, arrays, text-files, pseudocode

I am doing an activity that reads from the names and marks of each student from a text file, stores the names and marks in arrays and displays the arrays.

Although the objective of this activity is to only code the work, I want to take it a step further and write pseudocode and draw a trace table to understand the steps required to display the correct output.

I have done research, however, it does not suit my requirements because most of the example code is not written in java.

Additionally, I have included some of my code for further explanation. Thanks in advance.

A text file called LearnerNamesMarks.txt is used and looks like this:

```
Henry#87
Magda#91
Samantha#67
Daniel#78
```

A JFrame called LearnerMarksUI is created:

[image: LearnerMarksUI]

```
//Global variables
String [] arrNames = new String [20]; //stores the data from textfile
int [] arrMarks = new int [20]; //stores the data from textfile
int c = 0;
```

Button: that reads the names and marks from the text file and stores it in arrays

```
private void btnReadFromFileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    Scanner contents = null;
    try {
        contents = new Scanner (new FileReader("LearnerNamesMarks.txt"));
        while (contents.hasNext()) {
            String line = contents.nextLine();
            String [] arr = line.split("#");
            arrNames[c] = arr[0];
            arrMarks[c] = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
            c++;
        }
        contents.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        txaDisplay.setText(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Button: Displays from the arrays under suitable headings

```
private void btnDisplayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    txaDisplay.setText(String.format("%-15s%-15s%n","Names","Marks"));
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        txaDisplay.append(String.format("%-15s%-15d%n",arrNames[i], arrMarks[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: [What is a trace table?](https://www.bouraspage.com/repository/algorithmic-thinking/what-is-a-trace-table)  Your code comments in the question could be considered pseudo-code.  What part of your activity are you having problems with?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc. I am Having difficulty trying to create pseudocode and drawing up a trace table for my code. In general, I want to get a grasp of how to create pseudocode and drawing up a trace table for reading text files and storing them in arrays which are used to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're not understanding.

### Pseudocode

```
Create JFrame
    Create JPanel for buttons
        Create JButtons
    Create JPanel for output text
        Create JTextArea for output text
```

### Trace Table (for `btnDisplayActionPerformed`)

```
 1. Pad label to 15 spaces   "Names" -> "Names          "
 2. Pad label to 15 spaces   "Marks" -> "Marks          "
 3. Concatenate labels       "Names          Marks          "
 4. Set JTextArea text       "Names          Marks          "
 5. Set variable i           0
 6. Pad name to 15 spaces    "Henry          "
 7. Pad mark to 15 spaces    "87             "
 ...
```

By the way, you should use a monospaced font like Courier New for the `JTextArea`.